# Language issue when creating a meeting with the Zoom API

Tags: zoom-sdk

We are using the Zoom API's POST endpoint [https://api.zoom.us/v2/#{user_id}/meetings](https://api.zoom.us/v2/#%7Buser_id%7D/meetings) which on the front end opens a new tab in the browser (with an URL like https://us02web.zoom.us/s/82774997911) in order to open the Zoom computer client and launch the meeting. The issue is that this webpage's content is sometimes in French even for people who have all their settings (Mac + browser) in German. How can we make the webpage open for German users with the text in German? What does the language of the page depend on? There a 2 parts in the webpage: the pop-up to open the Zoom app and the content of the webpage itself and I need both to be in German.

I check the doc https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/methods/#operation/meetingCreate but didn't find any language parameter we could pass when making the call.